# Getting the User Agent with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, user-agent, prop

I'd like to get a script that can grab the user's user agent and prop it to an attribute.

I'm making a website problems contact form and I usually need to know what browser the user is using. How can I detect the user agent string and prop it as the value of an input element.

My html looks something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="UserAgent" name="User Agent" />
```

I want the user agent to be added to that as the value attribute so it would look like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="UserAgent" name="User Agent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10" />
```

Comment: You should not need any JavaScript to do this. Just read the user-agent-string from the HTTP header.

Comment: @Bergi: Actually that's only if you want it at the server-side. With JavaScript - **`navigator.userAgent`** should suffice as per accepted answer.

Comment: @Robin: OP *is* asking for server side, he wants to get the UA string posted with his contact form.

Comment: Not if you are generating parts of your application client side. Which seems to be what he was doing.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

### Pure Javascript

```js
document.getElementById('UserAgent').value = navigator.userAgent;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="UserAgent">
```

### jQuery

```js
$('#UserAgent').val(navigator.userAgent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="UserAgent">
```

Comment: Please add a non-JQuery alternative to the answer. So many new developers think that jQuery _is_ Javascript :-(

Comment: Will not work in jQuery 1.9 or later unless the jQuery Migrate plugin is included.

Comment: @Davlio this is not true. The example itself is using jQuery 1.11.1 and does not use the Migrate plugin.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield you are right! i said for [`$.browser`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) and dont could edit the comment.

Answer (score 52):

Original Q didn't say anything about jQuery. so

```
document.getElementById('UserAgent').value = navigator.userAgent;
```