# Is there a way to distinguish that my Javascript is running in a trident-based application vs. Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I've got a third party script that runs in many places on the web. I'd like to be able to tell when I'm running in an app vs. a browser. The user agent doesn't always help. Chrome provides the `chrome` object which has some different properties depending on the environment. Anyone know of anything similar for IE?

This is for a product similar to google analytics which can be implemented or wind up in many environments, and I'm trying to distinguish them better.

Comment: What exactly do you need to know this for? Also, what specific "trident-based application"s do you have in mind?

Comment: Please describe the problem you're actually trying to solve, not the solution you're trying to pursue.  If we knew why you needed to know the difference, then we could better know what answers might work best.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a general problem for ALL trident-based apps if possible: if my script shows up in the app, can I tell whether it's in an app or in a browser? That's the problem. It's for a product similar to google analytics which can be implemented or wind up in many environments, and I'm trying to distinguish them better.

Comment: _“if my script shows up in the app, can I tell whether it's in an app or in a browser? That's the problem”_ – no, that’s not the _problem_ – it is the poor _solution_ you have come up with so far to fix whatever the _real_ problem is. So now please tell us what that is, finally.

Comment: It sounds like the OP needs this ability as a data point for analytics, not as a solution to a technical challenge.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus has it correct: I want to know this as a data point to correlate with other factors.

Comment: I'm sure you thought of this, but isn't the global object fundamentally different in a browser vs some other environment?  Can't you check that to determine if you're in a browser?

Comment: Try and see what the `navigator` object has to say in different environments as well.

Comment: `window.location.hostname` may help. Ostensibly, an app doesn't sit on the web — whereas a website will.

Answer (score 1):

Check for **window.external**. If **window.external** is null then the web page is loaded into a Web Component, otherwise it is loaded via browser.

**window.external** enable you to communicate with **[ComVisible(true)]** instances which are enabled by default in the browsers. As long as your apps are not decorated with **[ComVisible(true)]**, you can distinguish between app and browser page consumption.

- Read more about window.external on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Does Maxthon count as a trident-based application? I just tried it there, and window.external was not null.

Comment: `window.external === null` evaluates to `false` for the Skype app on my PC.

Comment: Yes as written, windows.external is not null in the browser it is null when loaded in an application (Skype, C# Web Browser component...)

Comment: I tested this on the Skype desktop application, not on skype.com.

Comment: My point is that window.external should not be available on skype too

Answer (score 0):

The way Google Analytics checks for browser and device is the HTTP User-Agent header. It lets you check for browser, browser version, OS, OS version, and sometimes device:

http://jonathanstark.com/blog/windows-phone-8-user-agent-string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

You can parse this string in Javascript as well:
[Getting the User Agent with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450066/getting-the-user-agent-with-javascript)