# How to force Opera Mini users to view my website from other browsers on their phones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I run a couple of blogs and I do not want my sites to be viewed from a Opera Mini mobile browser. I want to force my links to open on other browsers present on their devices other than Opera Mini. Basically, when my link gets clicked on by Opera Mini users, I want my site to open on other browsers present.

I have tried all I could but to no avail. I shall appreciate every help I can get over this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Explaining why may help to obtain (useful) answers. Bear in mind you are wanting to override user's browsing preferences, so it is possible that you should not do this, or that it is correctly not possible to achieve.

Comment: Why in the world are you wanting to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the USER AGENT of Opera Mini and show a message to the users.... but you can't open automatically another app from browser website, there are security restrictions.

Here you can find the useragent string for Opera Mini: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Opera%20Mini/

Here a good answer for check the user agente via javascript: [Getting the User Agent with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450066/getting-the-user-agent-with-javascript)