# How can I detect if a web page is opened by a mobile browser or an app?

Tags: javascript, html, web, hybrid-mobile-app

if there is a web page which will be inserted into an app, it can be linked to another page within an app when I click somewhere on the web page because of the special link that can only be open within an app. However, if I want to make the same web page be opened within a mobile browser, I have to replace the special link.So,the prerequisite is that I need to detect if the web page is opened within an app or a mobile browser. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

1) Try to read the User Agent header from the http connections headers. It will show you the device that is connecting to your site. (proud to be hacked since header can be changed)
Here you have a php example on how to read user agent

```
<?php  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>
```

2) Add some logic on your app and on your web page in order to "recognize" each other.

A simple logic could be to add a parameter read on your web page that must have an specific value in order to allow access. Your app must call the url with the expected value on it parameter.

Comment: You should provide specifics on **what** to look for in the User Agent. For instance, how will the user agent different between the Android browser and the webview in the hybrid app?

Comment: Thanks torazaburo & Steven. I agree answer was not complete with some example. I already updated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the user-agent, each browser has a different user agent (name) which generally tells you what sort of device the browser is built for.

There are plenty of ways of retrieving the user agent with javascript check this previous StackOverflow question + answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450081/2012391).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the browser's useragent, which is a string. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

You can access it via Javascript and then perform conditionals based upon the result.

All browsers will return something slightly different so you will need to find something common to reduce the number of branches.

```
if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) {
    //Android browser, do something
}
```

Bunch of strings here: [UserAgent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/)