# Detect the widget is opening from mobile webbrowser or mobile Applicationmobile

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an HTML iframe which is hosted in both Android application in device and in browser.

User can access the iframe using mobile browser using crome or through Android application.

Is it possible to detect the difference using the html/js for Android app or Android web?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the android application created with?

Comment: What do you mean by *which is hosted* ? If for the app, the HTML file is on the device. You can check the page's location `location.protocol` to see if it is `https:` or `file:`

Comment: Hi, the page file is hosted in server, both mobile app or mobile web browser, hits an API and receive the iframe url and render it inside itself.it is an URL

Comment: It is not about Android app, I just what to receive whether people using it in Mobile app or though mobile browser.

Comment: This might help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822955/how-can-i-detect-if-a-web-page-is-opened-by-a-mobile-browser-or-an-app#35822988)

Comment: @Fishbite for your reference, both web browser in phone and application in phone ... Has the same response in useragent...