# Detect user agent jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to render different html for desktop and mobile on jekyll. I need something like:

```
{% if is_mobile %}
    <!-- mobile html -->
{% else %}
    <!-- desktop html -->
(% endif %}
```

Obviously I could just use javascript in the browser to determine this but I don't want to render the extra html for mobiles.

Maybe I could create a jekyll plugin and register the liquid tag but how can I get access to the user agent? Is there anyway I can get access to HTTP request parameters?

Comment: Jekyll is a static site generator - so the user only sees the generated pages with no FrontMatter or liquid templates or whatsoever - only the served output. You have to use JavaScript for that as someone already has answered below.

Answer (score 1):

In your layout you could use:

```
<div class="mobile">{% include mobile.html %}</div>
<div class="desktop">{% include desktop.html %}</div>
```

Then you should let js decide which one to show, as liquid has no access to the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jekyll I'm guessing you're not working with a backend which is typically how you'd process the User-Agent.

Perhaps your best approach is using accessing `navigator.userAgent` variable using plain-old Javascript.

More info here: [Getting the User Agent with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450066/getting-the-user-agent-with-javascript)