# How do I capture the browser being used to access a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

Let's say I am writing a simple web page containing two boxes, **name** and **pet name**. If an end-user were to browse to this site with any given web browser, how would I make a pop-up notification appear that displays the user's browser?

For example, if I browse to this page using Microsoft Edge or IE 11, how would I immediately have a dialogue box appear that states something along the lines of:

"You are using IE11" or "You are using Microsoft Edge"?

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing youre going to get to what you want is going through the browsers "User Agent String" in the frontend.

similar : [Getting the User Agent with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450066/getting-the-user-agent-with-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Here is also a library that can pass the value into a more usable state. 
https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js

Answer (score 0):

There are many other well documented Stack Overflow questions on how to detect browser version: [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Once you have the browser version, instead of using a console log as in the accepted answer above, an [alert](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_alert.asp) would do the trick of showing a dialog box with that information.

---

Update: Further down the page I linked is browser detection that works on Edge and IE. [Credit to Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080051/8137645)

```
navigator.browserSpecs = (function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, 
        M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return {name:'IE',version:(tem[1] || '')};
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem = ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem != null) return {name:tem[1].replace('OPR', 'Opera'),version:tem[2]};
    }
    M = M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null)
        M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return {name:M[0], version:M[1]};
})();
```