# How detect DuckDuckGo browser in Javascript or backend?

Tags: javascript, duckduckgo

How can I detect that a user is using the DuckDuckGo browser?

I have a page that links to the appropriate browser extension store. I need to detect the DuckDuckGo browser so I can display a message saying that the extension can't be added.

Currently the user is directed to the store of whatever browser DuckDuckGo is spoofing as, currently Edge on Windows. (Meaning that DuckDuckGo uses the same user agent as Edge.)

Note that Brave also spoofs as another browser, but they added a way to detect it: window.navigator.brave

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the User Agent with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450066/getting-the-user-agent-with-javascript)

Comment: ask their support if they add any  cookie or other header to be transparent?

Comment: Be forewarned that any user will be able to "spoof" any browser as either the code will run on hardware you don't control or rely on information in your backend you don't control.  There is no foolproof way to do this and likely (hopefully) will never be.

Comment: @possum no as its a browser that is spoofing (giving in correct user agent, behaving as if its chrome) that is part of the Duck duck go way and part of the client control of internet, pro privacy

Comment: Then you're out of luck.

Comment: You don't have to worry about it, nobody uses duckduck as a browser, most of us use it a search engine. And also, why do you care about duckduckGo? there are millions of browsers out there such as opera, yandex, tor browser and millions of others. Why is it just duckduckgo that you worry about